# How to disable product count in category sidebar, but not layered nav

Tags: catalog, category, admin

In a category view, Magento shows the product count of any child categories in the sidebar next to their names. When the viewed category is un-anchored, it only counts products explicitly assigned to that child but not to any deeper children it may have.

We have many high-level categories that have few or no products directly assigned but contain child categories that have lots of products.

Is there a means via the admin (as opposed to editing templates) to display this product count only for our lower-level categories (which are anchored/layered nav) and hide it for those higher-level (un-anchored) ones?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comment. No, afaik there is no admin configuration for this.

You can check `getIsAnchor()` or `getLevel()` in the template and hide or show this count

Comment: The original post says 'via the admin (as opposed to editing templates).